# Complexity of finding $d$ largest eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, matrices, linear-algebra

I know that for $n \times n$ matrix, it takes $O(n^2)$ time complexity to compute the largest eigenpair of the matrix using Power method or etc. I'm interested to further extend the case so that now we're interested in finding $d$ largest eigenpairs, but for a "symmetric" matrix. What is the time complexity of this algorithm and what is the name of the algorithm? My guess is this would take $O(dn^2)$ just because we need to perform the original method $d$ times. But, I think it's be faster if we assume the matrix is symmetric. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The power method takes $O(n^2)$ time *per step*. It is an iterative algorithm, and convergence is geometric. The absolute speed of convergence depends on the ratio between the two largest eigenvalues.

The usual generalisation of the power method to the top $d$ eigenpairs is the [Lancosz algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm), if the matrix is positive definite. There are also algorithms with similar convergence properties that find an eigenpair whose eigenvalue is close to a desired value, such as [LOBPCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOBPCG).